Using a JOLT Spec on NiFi, how do I remove arrays that only contain empty strings?
Here is the input JSON that I will put into the JOLT transformation processor in NiFi.
{
  "guests" : {
    "amy" : "amy",
    "theresa" : [ "Chef" ],
    "jim" : [ "Bear Specialist" ],
    "john" : [ "Tour Guide" ],
    "heather" : [ "" ],
    "brad" : [ "" ],
    "thomas" : [ "" ],
    "jane" : [ "" ]
  },
  "dataSchema" : "dataSchema",
  "data" : {
    "key1" : "value1",
    "key2" : {
      "key3" : "value3"
    },
    "label" : "dummyLabel",
    "campingEquipment" : {
      "someKey" : "someValue"
    }
  },
  "mountainRange" : {
    "elevation" : "8000",
    "temperature" : "50"
  }
}

And my expected output JSON is:
{
  "guests" : {
    "amy" : "amy",
    "theresa" : [ "Chef" ],
    "jim" : [ "Bear Specialist" ],
    "john" : [ "Tour Guide" ]
  },
  "dataSchema" : "dataSchema",
  "data" : {
    "key1" : "value1",
    "key2" : {
      "key3" : "value3",
    },
    "label" : "dummyLabel",
    "campingEquipment" : {
      "someKey" : "someValue"
    }
   },
   "mountainRange" : {
      "elevation" : "8000",
      "temperature" : "50"
  }
}

Notice that these fields were removed:
    "heather" : [ "" ],
    "brad" : [ "" ],
    "thomas" : [ "" ],
    "jane" : [ "" ]

Since they are empty strings in the arrays I do not want to include them in the resulting JSON object.
How would I construct a JOLT spec for this?
I tried this spec to remove the empty arrays.
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "guests": {
        "theresa": "=recursivelySquashNulls",
        "jim": "=recursivelySquashNulls",
        "john": "=recursivelySquashNulls",
        "heather": "=recursivelySquashNulls",
        "brad": "=recursivelySquashNulls",
        "thomas": "=recursivelySquashNulls",
        "jane": "=recursivelySquashNulls"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "guests": {
        "theresa": "",
        "jim": "",
        "john": "",
        "heather": "",
        "brad": "",
        "thomas": "",
        "jane": ""
      }
    }
  }
]

This did not work
and simply returned:
  "guests" : {
    "amy" : "amy"
  },

It removed all the fields with empty arrays.

Regarding your spec I have the following notes:

You cant use "recursivelySquashNulls" because you have empty
string not a null value and this functions works on null.Also, this
function doesnt work on array and it only works on complex objects.

The remove spec basically its going to remove anything that you
assign an empty string that is why the result is having amy only.


You can learn more about Jolt spec here.
For a solution, you can try the following spec:
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "guests": {
        //concatenate all guests value into string
        "*": "=join(',',@(0))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "guests": {
        
        "*": {
          //check if the value from the concat string above 
          // is equal to an empty string then remove using "":""
          // otherwise leave as is
          "": {
            "": ""
          },
          "*": {
            "$": "guests.&2"
          }
        }
      },
      "*": "&"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "guests": {
        // split the concat string back into the array
        "*": "=split('[,]',@(0))"
      }
    }
  }
]

Also since you are using nifi, there is another json transformation processor using jslt script called JSLTJsonTransform. Using the jstl script its much easier and less code in scenarios like this because the processor filter by default empty arrays. The jslt scrip will look like this:
{
    
  "guests":{ for(.guests)  .key: if(is-array(.value)) [for(.value) . if (.!="")] else .value }                           
             
    ,*:.
}

